# How to replace column names in JSON with array values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I want to replace all Json items before colons with my array respectively using JavaScript, how do I go about it.
As you may see below, is a Json object representing column names and first row. I want to replace column names position-wise with values from an array shown below.

```
// Json object
const Json = "{id: '1', name: 'Abednego Nasila', Reg: '123'}"
```

And below is my array

```
//array variable
const arr = ['myId', 'Student_name', 'Adm.no']
```

My desired output should be as shown below:

```
"{myId: '1', Student_name: 'Abednego Nasila', Adm.no = '123'}"
```

Thanks

Any help help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. 2. They aren't "column names," they're *property name*s.

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Hello, we should agree firstable that the idea behind is to *map* the properties to something we want because JS can not know what does id mean by itsown right ? in this case you can either use [Map data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or a simple JS object.
Also you have to precise a point: do you want this process to be applied on nested object or just one level objects?

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanations, let me correct some information on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your source JSON is, in fact, not a valid JSON string.
Therefore, to convert it into an object, I'm using a bit hackish solution. I wouldn't recommend using this approach in a real production environment. You probably want to convert your source string into a valid JSON first instead.

Anyway, here is how this can be achieved:

```js
// Json object
const Json = "{id: '1', name: 'Abednego Nasila', Reg: '123'}"

//array variable
const arr = ['myId', 'Student_name', 'Adm.no']

let source = {};
eval('source = ' + Json);

const result = {};
arr.forEach((field, index) => result[field] = Object.values(source)[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow! It works. Now I know where my problem was. Thanks so much.

Comment: @RAllen please read up on [eval](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-javascripts-eval-evil/)

Comment: @KooiInc, that's why I called this approach "hackish" and didn't recommend it on prod.

Comment: @AbednegoNasila would you mind picking my answer as a solution if it was helpful? Thanks!

Comment: @RAllen: why posting a 'hackish' answer if the hackishness is not necessary at all?

Comment: @KooiInc because another solution would be to implement a custom JSON parser, and I'm not sure that that would be the answer the asker is looking for. I'm happy to upvote your answer if you suggest a better, lightweight solution. But before that, in my opinion, this solution is good enough for the purpose, but it is not perfect though, hence my comment about hackishness.

Comment: @RAllen and Kooilnc. All that I wanted to know is how to replace those items of interest with my custom array and indeed all your approaches solves my problem. So I'll pick both of your approaches as solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that replaces the keys in a given JSON *String* with keys from a given Array.

Now go study:

- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
// create a real json string from an object
let REALJSON = JSON.stringify( {id: 1, name: 'Abednego Nasila', Reg: 123} );

console.log(`the JSON: ${REALJSON}`);

//array variable
const JSONReplaceKeys = (JSONStr, nwKeys) => {
  // parse the JSON
  const obj = JSON.parse(JSONStr);
  // create an Array with keys/values from obj
  const nwObj = Object.entries(obj)
  // use a reducer to create a new Object with the new keys
  .reduce( (acc, [key, value], i) => 
    ({...acc, [nwKeys[i]]: value }), {});
  // stringify the new Object
  return JSON.stringify(nwObj);
}

// let's try it
REALJSON = JSONReplaceKeys(REALJSON, ['myId', 'Student_name', 'Adm_no']);

console.log(`the new JSON ${REALJSON}`);
```

Comment: You have modified the source string and replaced it with a valid JSON :)

Comment: OP started out with an Object and later on added quotation marks afterward.